# C++11 numeric_limits<float> and arithmetic

Tags: c++, c++11

When I compiled this C++ code I didn't expect to see this output

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    const long double ldMinFloat = std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest();
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(20) << "ldMinFloat" << "= " << std::fixed << ldMinFloat << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(20) << "(ldMinFloat - 10)" << "= " << std::fixed << (ldMinFloat - 10) << std::endl;
return 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output

```
ldMinFloat          = -340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000
(ldMinFloat - 10)   = -340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000
```

Can someone be kind enough to explain why the subtraction is not -3402823466385288598117041834845169254**50**.000000???

Based on this [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) long double max value is +/- 1.797,693,134,862,315,7*10^308 and I don't really understand why the mantissa would explain this behaviour in basic integer arithmetic? or is it the implicit conversion from float to long double? or it's the operator << of std::cout?

Any idea to help me feel less stupid before going to sleep?

Comment: Can you write `sizeof(long double)` for your system, please?

Comment: Because its `ldMinFloat` ?!

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 sizeof(long double) = 12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `long double` cannot represent most values exactly, typically you are talking about big values (`std::numeric_limits<float>::max()`), so there are big gaps between values that are **exactly** representable by a `long double`.

Check the [`epsilon`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon) for `long double`, which is the difference between `1.0` and the smallest value greater than `1.0` that a `long double` can represent.

If you want to find the difference between the largest value lower than `ldMinFloat` that a `long double` can store and `ldMinFloat`, you can use the below **approximation**:

```
std::abs(ldMinFloat) * std::numeric_limits<long double>::epsilon()
```

This is (on my computer) `36893485948395847680`, so a `long double` cannot differentiate values between `340282346638528859811704183484516925440` and `340282346638528859811704183484516925440 +/- 36893485948395847680` (approximately... ) even if it can store values well below this.

---

**A more precision computation of the next representation value:**

Assuming 32 bits `float` and 64 bits `double` (I do not have 96 bits `long double` to test... ) and both uses IEEE 754 representation:

The lowest float (`-340282346638528859811704183484516925440`) has the following binary representation:

```
1 11111110 11111111111111111111111
```

Converted to a `double`:

```
1 10001111110 1111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000
```

The first representable number for a double below this is (just add 1 to the mantissa, and luckily it is easy for this number):

```
1 10001111110 1111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000001
```

Which is exactly `-340282346638528897590636046441678635008`. The difference between both values (computed in the code) is:

```
37778931862957161709568 // About half the value of the approximation (using double)
```

**How to compute this difference from `ldMinFloat`?**

You can compute this difference using the binary representation. You know that with IEEE754 the "conversion" is (without sign):

```
V = 2 ^ (E - shift) * M
```

Here, the exponent `E` is the same for both value<sup>1</sup>, so (`V1` is `ldMinFloat` and `V2` is the next representable value, I am assuming positive values for this, the sign does not matter here):

```
V2 - V1 = 2 ^ (E - shift) * M2 - 2 ^ (E - shift) * M1
        = 2 ^ (E - shift) * (M2 - M1)
```

`E` is `1050` in the above (`10001111110`) and the shift for 64-bits `double` is `1023`, so `E - shift = 127`:

```
V2 - V1 = 2 ^ 127 * (M2 - M1)
```

Here we are "lucky" because the last bit in `M1` (mantissa of `ldMinFloat`) is `0`, so the difference between `M1` and `M2` is:

```
M2 - M1 = 0.000...001b
//          <-------> 52 bits (51 zeros)
```

So the difference is:

```
V2 - V1 = (2 ^ 127) * 0.000...001b
        = (2 ^ 127) >> 52
        = 37778931862957161709568
```

<sup>1</sup> This all work smoothly because the last bit of the mantissa in `ldMinFloat` was `0`, if it was not the case, adding `1` to this mantissa could propagate the remainder and even change the exponent, so the computation would be harder.

Comment: Your scaling is incorrect. There is a non-trivial relation between `eps` and the actual gap between possible values that can be represented (at least I thought this was the case).

Comment: @rubenvb Yes, the scaling may be incorrect, bug the idea stay the same (I do not have time to check the exact scaling right now, I will update when I have time).

Comment: `std::numeric_limits::eps` should take an argument to get at this. You can use C99's `nextafter` but it still will be fishy to get the eps out of that...

Comment: @rubenvb based on the example of [epsilon doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon) is it std::abs(ldMinFloat+ldMinFloat-10) * std::numeric_limits<long double>::epsilon() so +/- 73786971896791695360 on my machine. This number feel crazy for integer arithmetic.

Comment: @MathieuGaraud Floating point types have a constant **relative** precision, but as soon as you start dealing with large number, the **absolute** precision diminishes quickly. The minimum float you provide is ~10\*\*38, while the difference you computed is ~10\*\*19, the relative "error" is still small.

Comment: @rubenvb I have added a precise computation of the difference between the two representable values using bit representation (unfortunately I do not have 96-bits `long double` so I can't compare with the approximation... ).

Comment: @rubenvb: IIRC, the relation between `eps` and the actual gaps may be complex, but the two can differ by no more than a factor of 2.0 (one bit) I think.

Comment: @Holt, thanks for the detailed explanation. An extra reason to not only be twice careful when dealing with float/double but 3 times ^^
La mantisse dans tous les mauvais coups!! ;)